# Custom authentication filter (implementing IAuthenticationFilter) is not firing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, basic-authentication

I have an ASP MVC 5 application, and I am having trouble getting a custom authentication filter to work.

I have created a custom authentication filter in a folder "CustomFilters" as shown below:

```
public class CustomBasicAuthAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IAuthenticationFilter
{

    public void OnAuthentication(AuthenticationContext context)
    {
        // does not fire... :(
    }

    public void OnAuthenticationChallenge(AuthenticationChallengeContext context)
    {
        // does not fire... :(
    }
}
```

And in my ProductController I decorated one of the methods as in:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{

    [CustomBasicAuth]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("clients/{id}/products")]
    public IEnumerable<Products> GetByClientId(int id)
    {

        return new List<Products>();
    }
```

For some reason, though, the OnAuthentication method in the CustomBasicAuth class never fires. I tried to decorate the whole controller, and also tried to load it globally, but none of it worked.

I read and followed a lot of online articles regarding this, and it looks like this should just work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the IAuthenticationFilter interface from System.Web.Http.Filters?

Comment: I am using one from System.Web.Mvc.Filters. I believe this is the correct one, as I tried the other one to make it work and failed.

Comment: Have you registered your custom filter in your webapi.config file?

Comment: try with :

public class CustomBasicAuthAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter{
public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext){
//TODO: all your code here
}

}

your Action

 [CustomBasicAuthAttribute]
pucblic ActionResult Index(){}

Comment: @mreyeros I have a Web.config file. Do I need to add a new config file? Like I said, I tried to load it globally by creating a file called FilterConfig.cs under App_Start and load it in the Global.asax. But that didn't work either.

Comment: @DanielGpeReyes I have tried that, but did not work either.

Comment: [CustomBasicAuth] are you sure that is the correct name? don't should be [CustomBasicAuthAttribute ]

Comment: I tried both. It uses some sort of a convention (like Rails I guess) so you could use it without the "Attribute" at the end.

Comment: @DanielGpeReyes: The "Attribute" suffix is superfluous when using it as an attribute.

Comment: ok, so no errors just the CustomBasicAuth never fires right?

Comment: @DanielGpeReyes That's right. No errors, no breakpoints in OnAuthentication and the other method are not hit. I am so baffled. I spent more than 10 hours trying to fix this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that you're implementing the wrong sort of IAuthenticationFilter for your controller type. Your controller class inherits from ApiController, so this appears to be a Web API project. 
To implement custom authentication for Web API, your CustomBasicAuthAttribute needs to implement the System.Web.Http.Filters.IAuthenticationFilter interface.
The methods on that are AuthenticateAsync and ChallengeAsync.

The CustomBasicAuthAttribute implementation shown clearly inherits from System.Web.Mvc.Filters.IAuthenticationFilter, as it's using OnAuthentication and OnAuthenticationChallenge. That attribute would fire correctly when placed on an action in a standard MVC controller, just not ones inheriting from APIController.

Comment: Yes inherit the correct type from System.Web.Http. or System.Web.Mvc. to suit the ApiController or Controller. My attributes weren't running because of this.

Answer (score 0):

This also happened to me, but in my case I had decorated the controller methods I wanted to protect with ONLY my custom basic authentication attribute, but completely forgot to also decorate with the normal MVC "Authorize" attribute. You need to still have the "Authorize" attribute there so that MVC protects the method or class and then fires your custom attribute filter..